# Possible bug in NSDateCompononents?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa, nsdate, nsdatecomponents

I was simply playing around with timers and i found this:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
     dFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; //instance variable

     NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

     unsigned unitFlags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
     NSDateComponents *dateC = [calendar components:unitFlags fromDate:date];
     [dateC setSecond:1];
     [dateC setHour:0];
     [dateC setMinute:0];

     NSDate *fireDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateC];
     [dFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
     [dFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
     NSLog(@"%@", [dFormatter stringFromDate:fireDate]);
 }
```

The output is amazingly : Oct, 4 12:00:01 AM

I'm trying to set up a timer-fire-date that starts some hours in the past.

Should i report this, or is there a way to make that date become something like oct, 4 00:00:01 AM???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12:00:01 AM is equal to 1 second after midnight. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: i'm rotfl about this. i was trying a lot of different options to make it change. but in the end was correct output.

Comment: Sure, I'm from a country that uses 24-hour system and sometimes have troubles with this too :)

Comment: I can't stop laughing... It's so funny!

Comment: If you want to be linguistically correct, 12pm doesn't exist.  Nor does 12am.  The second between 11:59:59am and 12:00:01pm is "meridian", and the other 12:00:00 is "midnight".  But, by convention in the US, noon is called 12:00pm and midnight is called 12:00am.

Comment: ("Meridian" refers to the sun being directly overhead -- at its highest elevation for the day.)